# django-crispy-forms: Align button with fields vertically

Tags: django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I've been struggling to get my form (including the button) in just one line using django-crispy-forms.

I eventually found a solution, but I decided posting the question together with the answer, in case somebody else faces the same problem.

Code in `forms.py` was as follows:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    [...]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-inline'

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
                    Field('From', placeholder='From'),
                    Field('To', placeholder='To'),
                    Field('Date', placeholder='Date'),
                    ButtonHolder(Submit('submit', 'Search', css_class='btn btn-primary'))
        )
```

But the button was appearing in a second line.

[image: button appears in a second line]

I tried as alternative

```
self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
```

but no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution based on [this post in github](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/issues/268).

That is to adapt the Layout by using a FormActions object:

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('From', placeholder='From'),
            Field('To', placeholder='To'),
            Field('Date', placeholder='Date'),
            FormActions(ButtonHolder(Submit('submit', 'Search', css_class='btn btn-primary')))
        )
```

And all fields and the button are perfectly aligned:

[image: desired result, all fields and button in one line]